# Extract Value from list of lists in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Lets say I have a list containing and int* list of lists How would I be able to extract the value of the int from this type of list? You could pattern match for the head of the list or the tail but how would you extract the int?

Comment: How do you know which int you want to extract? It would help if you gave an example of the input and the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always just make two pattern matches in a row

```
match [[1;2]; [3;4]] with
  | (firstrow::_) -> (
      match firstrow with ->
        | (x :: _) -> x
        | []       -> 0 )
  | _ -> 42
```

Its also OK to write pattern matches with multiple levels.

```
match [[1;2]; [3;4]] with
   | (x::_)::_  -> x
   | ([]::_)    -> 0
   |  _         -> 42
```

That said, you don't necessarily need to use pattern matching to access the list elements. You can also use List.map or one of the many other list-manipulation functions depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand which value you want to extract exactly, by let's say that you want to extract all integers in your `int list list` and don't want to write pattern matchings with multiple levels, you can first use the `List.flatten` function to obtain an `int list` and then do what ever you want to do:

```
let l = List.flatten [[1; 2]; [3; 4]] in    (* l = [1; 2; 3; 4] *)
List.iter print_int l                       (* iter, map or any other function *)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you think your list of lists as a matrix and you have the line column you want

`List.nth col (List.nth ln matrix)`

`List.nth` is nice to use in this case, with the info you got me i think this is what you want